# URL in Symfony automatically adds me params ?Symfony=

Tags: php, url, symfony1, parameters

I have a concern in my URL. Symfony automatically adds me params ?Symfony=
How to remove?

I think it's a server setting to change.

http://mysite.com/?symfony=123456789

Symfony: Symfony 1.4

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the session id.

Set `session.use_only_cookies` to 1 to only use cookies to store the session id on the client side.